# Is there any function in C++ equivalent to the get function for dictionary in python?

Tags: python, c++

Am trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-194/problems/making-file-names-unique/) problem statement.

It basically wants you to change the duplicates in the given vector to a unique form:

Ex: `["name","name","name1"]` -> `["name","name2","name1"]`... you get the idea

So I thought of using `std::map` to create a `dictionary` (I could also have used unordered_map here)

---

This is how I used the map:

```
std::vector<std::string> getFolderNames(std::vector<std::string>& names) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec_list_of_folders;
    std::map<std::string, int> map_of_names;
    for (const auto& name : names) {
        if (map_of_names.find(std::string(name)) == map_of_names.end()) {
            map_of_names.insert(std::make_pair(name, 1));
        }
        else {
            map_of_names[name] += 1;
        }
    }
    puts("");
    return vec_list_of_folders;
}
```

The function is still in debug mode (which explains why half the things in it are left uncoded)

I think the important part is:

```
for (const auto& name : names) {
    if (map_of_names.find(std::string(name)) == map_of_names.end()) {
        map_of_names.insert(std::make_pair(name, 1));
    }
    else {
        map_of_names[name] += 1;
    }
}
```

---

I wanted to know if there is an easy way to do this. Something like the following code in python:

```
file_names = ["file1", "file2", "file3", "file1"]
print(*file_names)
example_dict = dict()
for file_name in file_names:
    example_dict[file_name] = example_dict.get(file_name, 0) + 1  # this is the function I'm searching an equivalent for
print(example_dict)
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *important part* code is equivalent to:

```cpp
for (const auto& name : names) {
    map_of_names[name] += 1;
}
```

If `name` is not found, then the value type is default-constructed, and default-constructed int is 0.

You could do something similar in Python, using defaultdict:

```py
import collections
file_names = ["file1", "file2", "file3", "file1"]
print(*file_names)
example_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
for file_name in file_names:
    example_dict[file_name] += 1
print(example_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since map is sorted one way to do it could be to check if a name is the same as its neigbour.

```
if (!names.empty()) {
  for (auto it = std::next(names.begin()); it != names.end(); ++it) {
    if (std::prev(it)->first == it->first) {
      // handle this
    }
  }
}
```